# Python overriding sort explanation

Tags: python, sorting, overriding

How is the code below overriding the sort function?  I know you can use `__gt__` also just flipping the operators.  I cant seem to wrap my head around how it is sorting the list of objects passed.  Isnt it just returning true/false for each?

For example

```
accounts = [["paladin", "1", "1050"],
                ["archer",  "21", "995"],
                ["recruit", "3", "995"]]
```

Sorts by exp, if exp is the same, sorts by id.  The output should be:

```
sortAccounts(accounts) = ["paladin", "recruit", "archer"].
```

Code:

```
def sortAccounts(accounts):
        res = [Account(*account) for account in accounts]
        res.sort(reverse=True)
        return list(map(str, res))

class Account(object):
    def __init__(self, name, id, xp):
        self.name = name
        self.id = int(id)
        self.xp = int(xp)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.id > other.id if self.xp == other.xp else self.xp < other.xp

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  Yes, `__lt__` return True or False.  The sort function uses this information to do the sort: an object that is less than another gets moved earlier in the list.

Comment: I guess I am just confused on how the sorting is done.  Is it like a bubble sort where its comparing 2 objects at a time?

Comment: The actual algorithm is [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), but that doesn't really matter.  Any general sorting algorithm has to work by comparing pairs of elements; that's the only way to do it.  The differences between different sorting algorithms are just in which elements they compare and when.